# What are "hardware updates" in the context of Ubuntu's lifecycle?

Tags: updates, hardware

I see in [the Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) documentation that there is a difference made between "maintenance updates" and "hardware updates".

**What exactly are "hardware updates"?**

Are these:

- updates to currently supported hardware (say, I have an Intel Skylake which is already supported, and these are new updates for that equipment)
- support for new hardware, not supported before?
- both?
- something else?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, "**hardware updates**" means introducing support for more and newer hardware. "**Maintenance updates**" means receiving updates to fix emerging security issues and bugs.

Interim versions of LTS editions (.2 and above) are shipped with more recent kernel versions during a period indicated by "Hardware and maintenance updates" on the [diagram](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle). After that period, all users will remain on their current kernel version, which continues to be maintained to fix emerging security issues and bugs.

**More detail**

Hardware support is provided by the *linux kernel*. A long-term release of Ubuntu ships with a certain kernel series, which is during the entire support period maintained for security patches and fixing bugs. To enable hardware support for newer machines, **interim releases of long term support versions**, the "dot" versions, are released, build on a more recent kernel, hence also supporting more recent hardware.

When you initially install an Ubuntu LTS, you will in principle stay with your current kernel version throughout. If it works fine on your machine, that is perfectly fine, and the most stable option. That kernel is supported and maintained throughout the entire support period.

If you, however, decide to move to a new Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE), you will follow a [Rolling Update Model](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack). That means you will automatically move to a newer kernel when available. Moving to a HWE is opt-in: you can, but by default, you won't. After the "hardware and updates" period, you will stop receiving newer kernels. Your current kernel remains supported and maintained throughout the remainder of the support period.

Newer users downloading a newer version of the LTS installation ISO will automatically be on the new HWE stack introduced by that interim release. Users of the original release will stay on their current kernel line for the entire support period, until they opt in to go to the new HWE stack.

Comment: I disagree with that you can't roll back. On any LTS release you can always roll back to the initial kernel major version. HWE's are rolling and you can't roll back to a previous major kernel just because they are not supported.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have still a doubt, sorry if this is obvious: say I started on 18.04 with my hardware in 2018. The hardware does not change and everything works fine. I see that somewhere in 2020 I hit the EOL of hardware updates. Does this mean that no more hardware updates are released at all, or only new hardware is not added anymore but the hardware supported until that "somewhere in 2020" will get updates?

Comment: cont'd: (you say "To enable hardware support for newer machines (...)" and this is the part where I am not sure if there is a split between "new hardware" and "hardware known so far")

Comment: @Pilot6 you are probably right. It might be just a matter of installing the original kernel which is in the repo's, booting to it and removing the newer kernels. I deleted the statement: it is not very relevant here.

Comment: "Hardware update" in the diagram means that the edition is updated for newer hardware. The original kernel of the LTS is maintained for the full five years of support.

Comment: I expanded a bit in my answer: the original kernel remains supported throughout the support period, so will receive security and bug fixes throughout. "Hardware update" in the diagram only refers to the newer kernels.